# Querying MongoDB Flask

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I've 2 models :-

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()

class BlogPost(Document):
    title = StringField()
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

How can I query `Blogpost object` having comment as `hello how are you?`, something like

```
BlogPost.objects.get(comment.content='hello how are you')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, technically you only have "one" model, which contains an embedded defintion of another class. As such then all you need to do is match the embedded property. There is a set syntax to this:

```
BlogPost.objects(comments__content="hello how are you")
```

So use the double underscore for a property of the parent name. This is how mongoengine does this in a very "django" like way, as opposed to the "dot notation" form as used by the base driver or "raw" queries itself.

This is actually covered in the mongoengine manual under: [Filtering Queries](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries)